# How to lock an IP address to a MAC address

Tags: networking

I know the title is not the best possible title.

Currently, every server on my network may use any static IP by simply configuring it in the OS level.  What I'm trying to accomplish is allowing a specific IP address only be used with a specific MAC address.

So for example, I should be able to set **192.168.1.1** and **192.168.1.2** can **only** be used by the MAC address **00:fe:94:82:05:32**.

If another NIC, with a different MAC address, let's say **00:fe:94:82:05:31**, wants access to use 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.2, *something* should deny its request.  What would that *something* be? I assume it should be the router or a level 3 switch. If so, what feature should I search for in specs of routers to buy?

Comment: Is this about security? If so you should be aware that finding out the MAC of the device you're trying to impersonate and setting your device to use that MAC is trivial.

Comment: It's a virtualization environment. I'm not sure the owner of the virtual machine can change its MAC

Comment: Then if I were you, I'd find out for sure before I built an entire security edifice about the proposal that they can't.  You're busily rejecting a whole bunch of normal suggestions (eg via the DHCP server) on the basis that the end-user can easily bypass them; if that turns out to be true for MAC addresses as well, as I strongly suspect it is, you're wasting a lot of time here.

Comment: @ispirto Every virtualisation hypervisor can be configured to use arbirary MAC addresses. It may not be obvious how to do it. In some cases it's not even in the manual, but it is always possible. If you can't control the hyper-visor you are asking for the impossible as MAC-addresses are NOT fixed..

Answer (score 3):

You would need an intelligent switch to do this on the network. I don't know if there is a VM management tool that can prevent users from adding another or changing IP's on their guest.

In Cisco-land you're looking for port-security to keep someone on a different port from spoofing the mac, and IP source guard (IPSG) to inspect the mac/IP combination and/or dynamic arp inspection (DAI) to prevent ARP spoofing.  IPSG and DAI depend on DHCP snooping or a user-configured table, so it can add quite the overhead to your operation.

Other vendors(Juniper/Extreme/Force10/etc...) can do the same security features but the names might differ from what I mentioned.  All vendors will have their own hardware/software/licensing requirements that you will need to work out with your vendor/VAR.

Also, there are complications to configuring this type of security and a misconfiguration can be really hard to troubleshoot, and depending on your network it might not be possible to provide this level of security.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anything handing out IPs on your 192.168.1.X network?

If you are using a DHCP server, you can create a DHCP reservation, which locks a MAC address to a specific IP.  The servers would be set to use DHCP and when contacting the DHCP server will pull the reserved address for that host.

You could potentially create static ARP entries for each IP - MAC on your router.  However, that would just prevent Layer 3 communication from a host that tries using an address not matched to it's MAC.  To prevent all communication you would need to create static ARP entries in every host in the Layer 2 domain the host could need to communicate with and prevent people from being able to change those entries (sounds like a management nightmare to me).

Comment: No, there is no DHCP server. However, it's not relevant. I know I can simply static map on the DHCP server conf to hand out the right IPs to the right MAC addresses. However, it's not the case. What I'm looking for a *strict* environment.

Comment: It is relevant because that is how you specify that a MAC gets a specific IP.  What do you mean by a "strict" environment?  The "something should deny it" would be your DHCP server.  Even still if the people managing the servers have rights to access TCP/IP properties they could still change to a static IP.

Comment: I meant, even they want to use a static IP of 192.168.1.1, they shouldn't be able to that, by strict.

Comment: This would not work as the network gear will not enforce such binding, and setting the IP address manually will circumvent your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mate, if you really have this sort of environment, the only answer to your problem is a well defined Policy of what may and may not be done.

There is no technology capable of doing what you need. Port protection, firewall matching the pair MAC/IP or whatever other solution won't prevent the owner of the VM to simply change it's IP Address.

But a real policy, with clear rules and punitive to who break it, will have more effect to it.

Comment: Agree, no technical solution is 100% reliable and will be very complicated and expensive. And you still need a policy in place. Might as well go policy only, with frequent checks (can be easily automated) if everyone plays by the rules.

Answer (score 1):

How can they use "any static IP"? If you have a static IP set then that's what it uses. Once you set the Static IP you should keep it and document it for each server.

"Internet Protocol addresses are assigned to a host either anew at the time of booting, or permanently by fixed configuration of its hardware or software. Persistent configuration is also known as using a static IP address"

So are you using static IPs or DHCP? Or are you just in a lab environment that you're changing IPs all the time?

I guess my suggestion is setting up a specific VLAN with the servers you want to keep static IP addresses and then putting the ones that are changing on another VLAN.

Comment: I'm not managing every server on the network, so the owners can simply configure a static IP on their server and use 192.168.1.1. I'm trying to disallow that.

Comment: You can't control what IP people set on the equipment under their control.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but if you're in an organization that has a bunch of servers I assume there is some sort of policy enforcement? You're not about to walk into my building and set up a server using what ever IP you want. Although if you are in a position that allows people to do that then I think a VLAN would be your best bet. If it's just the two you need then make a vlan with just 192.168.1.0 /30 and put everyone else on a different vlan

Comment: @Ericrobert - I was responding to the comment. Your suggestion is perfectly valid.

Comment: There are about 120 virtual machines on this /24 network. So what I should do is to create different VLANs for each virtual machine?

Comment: That depends on this virtual machine network setup. If they are all clustered and have a central management point such as vCenter Server you should be able to configure the virtual network to separate those servers into their own vlan / network. You can't configure a network properly that you don't have authority over though. I'm trying to wrap my head around what sort of infrastructure/organization would have 120 VMs that don't have dedicated static IP schemes and are un-managed by a central entity.

Comment: @CoryJ - Didn't mean to make it sound like I was attacking you. I think this question and lack of any information on the situation or rest of the network has me frustrated. It's my OCD freaking out that there is an un-managed server architecture out there like this.

Comment: It's cool @Ericrobert. It's an organizational problem that's probably better solved with management and policy then with technology. The only decent tech solution would be something like you suggest: to not let ports onto the "real" VLAN until they've somehow proven that they're not stupid or malicious.